# cloud function to send FCM from specific app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

i have one xCode project that contains two applications(two targets), i'm trying to send FCM from a specific target but it always send from the first target!

in index.js file

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotificationForCompany = functions.firestore.document('test/{referenceID}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

    var theTitle = "Not"

    let payload = {
          notification: {
              title: theTitle,
              sound: 'default',
          }
      };

    const allTokens = await admin.firestore().collection('users').get();
    const tokens4 = [];
    allTokens.forEach((tokenDoc) => {
      if (tokenDoc.data().instanceIdToken){
        tokens4.push(tokenDoc.data().instanceIdToken)
      }
    });

    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens4, payload);  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sent notification based on topic. For example `project-one-topic-unique-user-id` and `project-two-topic-unique-user-id`. So now send notification based on topic

```
let message = {
   "topic": "project-two-topic-unique-user-id"
    "notification": {
       title: theTitle,
        sound: 'default',
    }
 }
}

admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
     // Response is a message ID string.
     console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

Comment: as my understanding of topics it's for registers users not applications, i already have a separate users db for the second application, so the notification will be sent to them with no issue, but the notification came from the wrong application, how to specify the admin.messaging to be sent from the second app.

Comment: it was my mistake, i forgot to replace the collection for the second app.